# Maximal graph that does not contain Hamiltonian cycle

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

My lecture notes in Graph Theory states that a graph of order $n$ and with size (= number of edges) $\binom n 2-(n-2)$ is the maximal graph that does not contain a Hamiltonian cycle.

My question now is how to find such a graph? How can I construct a graph of order $n$ such that this is true?

For the proof that no greater size can be achieved there was a similar question on this site: [Proving that a graph of a certain size is Hamiltonian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30833/proving-that-a-graph-of-a-certain-size-is-hamiltonian)

This can be used to prove that no greater size can be achieved, so I am not interested in this part, only in the constructon part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** If a vertex has degree 1, it can't be part of a cycle.

Comment: Thanks, I did not think of that, this explains the term $\binom n 2$, where does $n-2$ come from?

Comment: @UlrichOtto What is the degree of a vertex in a complete graph with $n$ vertices?

Comment: Degree is $n-1$

Comment: Oh ok, I have to exclude this case because complete graph contains Hamiltonian cycle, but there is still n-2 instead of n-1

Comment: @UlrichOtto Read my hint ... What is $(n-1) - 1$?